# Posting an author's accepted manuscript on arXiv

Tags: publications, journals, copyright, arxiv

Many journals allows one to post an author's accepted manuscript online, provided some embargo period has lapsed and an acknowledgment is included. For example, for Springer Nature journals, an acknowledgement of the following form should be included:

“This is a post-peer-review, pre-copyedit version of an article published in [insert journal title]. The final authenticated version is available online at: [http://dx.doi.org/[insert](http://dx.doi.org/%5Binsert) DOI]”.

I have two question about arXiv.

**Question 1**:
Is it enough to include this acknowledgement in arXiv's *Comments* section, without including it in the source file?

**Question 2**:
Is it OK not to write the sentence above altogether, but to fill out arXiv's *Journal reference* and *DOI* fields?

Comment: Probably going to depend on the journal. And also the country the journal is published in. And maybe the country the author is in. Copyright is a messy complicated and varied subject.

Comment: About question 2, the journal says you should include the statement, so why would you think it’s okay not to include it?

Comment: No need to do too much hairsplitting. The journals want a link to the published version and a clear statement of the status of the arXiv version. Was anyone ever sued for incorrectly formatting this statement or putting it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**: Copyright statements should go into the full text. [Copyright statements should not appear in arXiv's metadata](https://info.arxiv.org/help/prep.html#comments) (scroll down a little).

**Question 2**: Please *do* fill in the metadata with the `Journal-ref` and the journal-assigned `DOI`.